# WP7: Get phone name

Tags: windows-phone-7, device

I'm looking for a simple information.
I want to get the name of the device the user is currently using.

For example, I want to get "Eric's Phone" (like in Zune).

Is it possible? I looked for the DeviceExtendedProperties (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) or the UserExtendedProperties see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.trygetvalue%28v=VS.92%29.aspx))

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"That information is not available to third-party apps."

Credit : [Krome Studios](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/80271/485531.aspx#485531)