# How can I get the device name as defined in Zune?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In Zune, one can change the phone's name via Zune -> settings -> phone -> sync options. For example, I changed the phone's name to 'myphone lumia 900'.

How can I get that name? Using `DeviceStatus.DeviceName` it only returns the model, in this case 'lumia 900'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7: Get phone name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616546/wp7-get-phone-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party apps cannot get that information I'm afraid.

Comment: I’m so tired from these Microsoft restrictions, treating us, the developers, as babies.

Comment: I don't know why they restricted it in WP7 but in WP8 you can.